# Using STREAM_RING and STREAM_NOTIFICATION independently

Tags: android, android-notifications

The AudioManager class provides different stream types for ringer  and notifcation (STREAM_RING & STREAM_NOTIFICATION).
But using setStreamVolume(int streamType, int index, int flags) for one stream affects the other.

For example, the following:

```
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 4, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI),
```

changes both ring volume and notification volume to 4.
Check volume using:

```
mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(int streamType)).
```

So, the question is, why two different stream types when they're interchangeable? Also, is there a way to use the two independently?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Android 8.0 and 9.0